# Cisco Switch 2950T-24 can not create multi VLANs

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

I follow a tutorial for creating multi vlans in Cisco Switch, but get bellow errors:

```
Switch(config)#vlan 21, 22, 25-30 
                    ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Switch(config)#vlan 21,22,25-30 
                    ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Switch(config)#vlan 21,22
```

---

**EDIT-01**

I use the Cisco Packet Tracer 7.2.0.0226. and the Switch is `2950T-24`.

Comment: What software version are using?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. Maybe you saw something related to multiple VLAN assignment for trunk interface, like `switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,2,5-10,15,20,22-25`

Comment: @AndreyProkhorov I mean I want to create multi VLAN in a Cisco Switch.

Comment: Try surrounding the commas and dashes with spaces. That used to be required. For example, `vlan 21 , 22 , 25 - 30`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VLAN range feature was first integrated into Cisco IOS release 12.1(9)EA1 for the Cisco Catalyst 2950/2955 Series.

Test run on an old Cisco 2950:

```
Switch(config)#vlan 21,22,25-30
Switch(config-vlan)#
Switch(config-vlan)#no vlan 21,22,25-30
Switch(config)#
```

Thanks to  Marc 'netztier' Luethi.

Documentation page 2-342, section ***vlan (global configuration)***:
https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2955/software/release/12_1_12c_ea1/command/reference/cr2955.pdf

Comment: While I have no old catalyst at hand to cross-check, I find it particular that the document you linked mentions no catalyst switches (which were indeed been available back in 2002), and dont' even mention Layer2 VLANs as such, only 802.1q tagged subinterfaces of routers.  The document does not show how to define L2-VLANs by group.

Comment: Some of the older switches and IOS actually required spaces before and after the commas and dashes. The configuration templates I have still do that because it will work with both old and new switches.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi the document explains the software train 12.2(13)T and it's features introduced, when it came out. This version was only supported on the Cisco 6400, 7200 and ASR 7401 to begin with, but it explains when Cisco introduced the VLAN range command. I suspect, that all Catalyst series hereafter had the feature added.

Comment: @RonMaupin You are very correct, older IOS versions required spaces.

Comment: @Cown: The feature you quote describes how to create a number of dot1q tagged subinterfaces on routers that is restricted to sequential numbering, for both subinterface ID and VLAN ID.  The suggestion of `vlan 22 , 23 , 25`  as a command doesn't even follow what that document says (which works with `interface range ...`. Creating a (set of) arbitrarily numbered L2-VLAN(s) is something else entirely, touching completely different parts of device logic, even pertaining to completely different device classes. So it's still apples vs oranges.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi i guess we read it differently then.

Comment: https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2955/software/release/12_1_12c_ea1/command/reference/cr2955.pdf, p 2-432, in the section about `vlan (global configuration)` explains that "You can enter a single
VLAN ID, a series of VLAN IDs separated by commas, or a range of VLAN IDs
separated by hyphens." The doc is from feb2003 (the oldest i managed to find) and that the feature  had been introduced with 12.1(9)EA1 - so (in terms of release trains) even before _sequentially numbered subinterface range with sequentially numbered dot1q tags_ came to the routers.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi i guess you were right then. I'll update my post with your findings. Oh and the page was 2-342, not 2-432.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple VLANs cannot be *created* in a 1-liner on a classic Catalyst IOS Switch.

But you can prepare a command sequence in your preferred text editor and then copy & paste it into the terminal window ofyour switch (ssh, telnet, console...)

```
vlan 1
 name MY-VLAN-1

vlan 20
 name THIS-IS-VLAN-20

vlan 30
 name ENGINEERING-VLAN
```

The "name" line is optional and of almost no technical relevance, but recommended - you'll have to define your own style and guidelines to naming VLANs.

---

**EDIT:**
Erratum: 
There *is* a way to configure multiple VLAN IDs with a 1-liner, separating the list of vlans with commata or defining ranges with hyphens. As other commentators pointed out, older releases need spaces between the numbers and commata or hypens.

See solution as proposed by Cown.

---

As Andrey has pointed out, *manipulating* the scope of a given (set) of VLAN(s) can happen in a 1-liner: The `switchport trunk allowed vlan` command (in interface configuration mode) works with a set of VLANs on a single line.

```
interface FastEthernet X/Y
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q      ! <-- some platforms still need that one
 switchport nonegotiate                    ! <-- suggested, if you don't run DTP or VTP
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,20,30
```

Adding to that, I strongly suggest to exclusively work with  `switchport trunk allowed vlan add ...` and `switchport trunk allowed vlan remove ...` from the start. Sooner or later in your networking career, you'll learn why if you don't [1].

---

[1] It is probably *the* one classical human factor error in switched networking: to forget the add/remove keywords when "let me just add that new VLAN to to this 802.1q trunk" - which reduces that trunk to just the VLAN you were about to add. Dpending on where this happens, this can bring down an entire network within a few seconds.

Comment: The document linked is for 802.1q tagged subinterfaces for routers, not for catalyst switches. "Supported Platforms" doesn't even mention a switch.

Comment: I'll give you a vote tomorrow, i exhausted all my votes for today.